# Setup / Migrate Google App Engine in / to Asia Zone

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am developing application with PHP and SQL cloud.
Currently the app engine and SQL cloud instance are all launched in US.
I would like to know how I can setup / migrate those instance to Asia zone to minimize the latency from Hong Kong / Singapore.

It will be great if I can manage this through web, not terminal / command mode.

Comment: App Engine currently only supports running from US and EU zones.

Comment: Thanks Mars.
So, what are the services available for Asia zone ?

Comment: Both Compute Engine & CloudSQL are available in Asia zones.

Comment: Many thanks, hope the appengine service can be launched in Asia very soon